# Understand if DVD Rom is burned or Pressed

Tags: dvd, optical-media

I have the following hardware and software available:

- Desktop Computer with Ubuntu, Windows and Mac OS X
- USB CD/DVD reader and writer.l
- Laptop with built in BD, DVD and CD reader and writer, with Ubuntu and Windows.

I've got a Video (PAL) DVD disc of an event I went to, I'd like to know if it is an ink-based DVD-R that has been burned or a Pressed DVD ROM. How can I do this?

**Why?** I wanna know what to do: can I keep it as-it-is (pressed) or I have to digitalize it (burned)?

I accept answers that involve looking at how a disc reflects light or stuff... - not necessarily computery-based! :)

Comment: Generally  Disk Writer software is capable of identifying the type of disk. Most have a menu option like Disk Info that shall tell you the type of disk including if it's -R, +R, ROM etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disk Writing Software are designed to seek this information about all relevant parameters like Type of Disk, Complete/Incomplete, Free Space if any, Bootable etc and most have a menu option to just seek the Disk Info. This will anyways reveal the type of Media be it CD/DVD, -R, +R, ROM etc.

See sample screenshot below from BurnAware Free Application. I inserted DVD-R, DVD-ROM, CD-R & CD-ROM media in the drive and each time it correctly displayed the type. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Do you know where exactly in the data header this information is?